# Parse Linux Command with Python

Tags: python, linux

Here's a quick snippet of my code using pexpect:

```
child.expect('tc@')
child.sendline('ps -o args | grep lp_ | grep -v grep | sort -n')
child.expect('tc@')
print(child.before)
child.sendline('exit')
```

and then the output:

```
user@myhost:~/Python$ python tctest.py 
tc-hostname:~$ ps -o args | grep lp_ | grep -v grep | sort -n
/usr/local/bin/lp_server -n 5964 -d /dev/usb/lp1
/usr/local/bin/lp_server -n 5965 -d /dev/usb/lp0
{lp_supervisor} /bin/sh /usr/local/lp/lp_supervisor /dev/usb/lp0 SERIAL#1 /var/run/lp/lp_pid/usb_lp0
{lp_supervisor} /bin/sh /usr/local/lp/lp_supervisor /dev/usb/lp1 SERIAL#2 /var/run/lp/lp_pid/usb_lp1

user@myhost:~$
```

There's 4 lines of output. The first two lines show with printer port the usb device is assigned to (EX: first line shows port 5964 is assigned to lp1)

The 3rd and 4th lines show which device serial number is assigned to which usb port. (EX: SERIAL#1 is assigned to lp0)

I need to somehow parse that output so I can do the following:

```
If SERIAL#1 is not assigned to 5964:
    run some command
else:
    do something else
If SERIAL#2 is not assigned to 5965:
    run some command
else:
    do something else
```

I'm not sure how to manipulate that output so I can get the desired variables. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, all you need is the serial numbers (5964, 5965) or you need additionally the SERIAL#1 and SERIAL#2 as variables?

Comment: made an edit of my IF statement to clarify. 5964 and 5965 are not the serial numbers, they are the printer ports. I need to check which serial number is assigned to which printer port then execute commands based on that.

Comment: Yes, you're right that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract port and serial information from pexpect data using `re.findall` and do something like this

```
import re
data = child.before
ports = re.findall(r'lp_server -n (\d+)', data)
# ['5964', '5965']
serials = re.findall(r'(SERIAL#\d+)', data)
# ['SERIAL#1', 'SERIAL#2']

list(zip(ports, serials))
# [('5964', 'SERIAL#1'), ('5965', 'SERIAL#2')]

for serial, port in zip(ports, serials):
    # Check if serial and port matches expectation
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by using dictionaries to build relationships between device serial numbers and printer ports:

```
inString = """/usr/local/bin/lp_server -n 5964 -d /dev/usb/lp1
/usr/local/bin/lp_server -n 5965 -d /dev/usb/lp0
{lp_supervisor} /bin/sh /usr/local/lp/lp_supervisor /dev/usb/lp0 SERIAL#1 /var/run/lp/lp_pid/usb_lp0
{lp_supervisor} /bin/sh /usr/local/lp/lp_supervisor /dev/usb/lp1 SERIAL#2 /var/run/lp/lp_pid/usb_lp1"""

inString = inString.split("\n")

matches = dict()
serials = dict()

for i in range(len(inString[:2])):
    lp = inString[i][-3:]
    printerPort = int(inString[i].split("-n ")[1][:4])
    matches.update({lp:printerPort})

for i in range(2,len(inString)):
    t = inString[i].split(" ")
    lp = t[3][-3:]
    serial = t[4]
    serials.update({serial:lp})

finalLookup = dict((k,matches[v]) for k,v in serials.items())
print(finalLookup)
```

Output:

```
{'SERIAL#1': 5965, 'SERIAL#2': 5964}
```

Then you can do:

```
if not finalLookup['SERIAL#1'] == 5964:
    run some command
else:
    do something else
if not finalLookup['SERIAL#2'] == 5965:
    run some command
else:
    do something else
```